# Why does array returns classical Enumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, enumerator, ienumerator

While studying about `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<T>`, I came accross the following statement:-

> If we call GetEnumerator() on any collection, we mostly get the type-safe version ie "generic" version,  notable exception in this case is array which returns the classical(non-generic) version.

My question is that:-
Why do arrays return "classical" Enumerator upon calling the `GetEnumerator()` function, but other data-structures like `List<T>` and others return the generic Enumerator?

```
string[] tempString = "Hello World!" ;
var classicEnumerator = tempString.GetEnumerator() ; // non-generic version of enumerator.
List<string> tempList = new List<string> () ; 
tempList.Add("Hello") ; 
tempList.Add(" World") ; 
var genericEnumerator = tempList.GetEnumerator() ; // generic version of enumerator.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just because `Array` predates generics (which were introduced in .NET 2.0).

Actually, arrays also implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, but they do it [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). So you can do that:

```
string[] tempString = new[]{"Hello World!"}; ;
IEnumerable<string> enumerable = tempString;
var genericEnumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator() ; // generic version of enumerator
```

Comment: Which is documented at "important": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx